# How to validate the email address in Firebase ssecurity rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been saving user data under a reference ID, and some user info containing email address. I want to make the data available, but prevent people guessing ID's and seeing if there is info behind it.

I only want to give the data if they provide me the ID AND the email address they registered with.

So I have this data stored in Firebase:

```
{ "data" : {
   "ms12345678" : { 
       "name" : "John Doe",
       "age"  : 40,
       "email" : "johndoe@domain.com"
    }
}
```

So doing `var ref = firebase.database().ref("data/ms12345678")` should fail, unless I provide `johndoe@domain.com` as well.

I am not sure what approach I should take here. I don't want users to authenticate, but provide them with a link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can verify that the accounts email address matches that value with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.token.email === data.child('email').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See the [documentation on `auth.token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken) for a list of the properties available.

Alternatively you can require that the user **knows** the email address. To do this, embed the email address into the path of a user:

```
{ "data" : {
   "ms12345678" : { 
      "johndoe@domain,com": {
         "name" : "John Doe",
         "age"  : 40,
         "email" : "johndoe@domain.com"
      }
   }
}
```

With this, you can restrict read-access to people that know the full path:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$uid": {
        "$email: {
          ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```